# elementary OS hangs a lot

Tags: release-hera, amd, lenovo, black-screen

**Issue**
Lately, my elementary OS has started hanging a lot. Like a few times a week. At times, these hangs make the icons or buttons, etc. on the screen change into white rectangles. Then, I have to forcefully restart my PC and I lose important unsaved stuff.

**Specifications**
eOS Version: 5.1.7 Hera (Built on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS)
Kernel: 5.4.0-58-generic
Laptop: Lenovo Thinkpad E585 (with AMD processor & graphics card)

**Fix not working**
I reinstalled elementary OS last night and by now it has already hanged thrice. The last time I noticed the screen turns black after a few seconds of the hanging.

I am wondering if anyone else is suffering from a similar issue and have found the solution? I was thinking of moving to some other Linux distribution but I sort of like eOS and find it hard to leave it.

Comment: The TV attached to my laptop could not be the cause of the issue since the issue appeared even after I detached the TV from the laptop.

Comment: When similar freezes happend on one of my laptops, I ended up replacing the SSD the with a new one. You can also try booting into an older kernel, just to see if the problem persists?

Comment: To add to the above, I'd look in the logs afterwards. There's a wonderful GUI way to do this with `sudo apt install ksystemlog`. It pulls in a few dependencies, making it a bit bulky for a log viewer, but I hold the opinion that it's worth it. In the log, you can look for errors and then potentially find solutions via your favorite search engine - or ask for help with much more accurate information besides the rather generic information contained in your existing question.